# Nice: *Low* priority using *more* CPU

Tags: ubuntu, top, nice

(Ubuntu 14.04 server, 8 cores, 16GB RAM)

When running 3 scripts in parallel that utilise the same (other) script, the inverse of what I expect to happen occurs when "renice-ing" the processes as they are running.

Those with higher niceness - i.e. *lower* priority, use more CPU

Those with lower niceness - i.e. *higher* priority, use less CPU

[image]

It remains (pretty much) like this throughout execution.  Any ideas? Have I fundamentally misunderstood what niceness is?

(I also tried renice-ing the parent scripts but it didn't seem to make a difference. `sudo top` had to be run to have permission to do all this.)
(Also I think the times can be ignored, as `3167` was the second `mgiza` to be run by the parent - it originally had one with a lower PID)

---

**Edit**: All three of these processes are happy (and allowed) to go up to using 800% CPU!

Comment: You shouldn't ignore the `TIME+`, that's the total CPU time used. Clearly the higher priority processes have enjoyed a far higher share of CPU time, and are now chilling out. Finally the low priority process gets its day in the sun.

Comment: I understand what you mean but as I said, they are completely mispresentative; the shorter time for `3167` is because it had reached a later point in the parent script, and so was already on its second running of `mgiza` whereas the others were still on their first.

Comment: In that case, I'd look at the data and operating parameters - the high priority runs might have been more I/O bound (or waiting for some other such resource), instead of being CPU bound.

Comment: I believe (without certainty) that the program whacks almost all it needs into memory at the start - in either case, does `nice` value affect I/O priority in any way?

Comment: for that there's ionice

Comment: 800% is wanted, as you have 8x100% total cpu available (8 cores). if it was amounting to less than than then some cpus would be idling. your -20 (low nice value, ie HIGHER priority) are enjoying some time off, while the 1st one is probably busy right now and takes the remaining cpu available (along with everything else currently running)

Comment: .. is wanted? CPU (total) usage stays in the high 90s% throughout. If just one proc. is running then it will be just shy of 800% usage.

Comment: @csey: if you only had 1 core, cpu should stay within 0-100%. with 8 cores it will go up to 800 (or more : cpu % is a "computed/projected" value and sometimes is even higher than the theoritical limit). And you say "usage stays in the high 90s% throughout" when the images says: 490.7% + 143.1% + 143.1% (+ others underneath)

Comment: I fully understand how the CPU column displays information, and when I said "CPU (total) usage" I was referring to the total usage - the summary at the top which refers to all available cores.

Answer (score 2):

It totally depends on what the processes are doing.  A *nice* process is happy to let other processes past them in the run queue, but will still get 100% of the CPU (or however much it needs) if there is no other process that needs it at the moment.

Comment: Please see my edit!

Comment: Also - regardless of which process is given which value, or be the value -20, 0 or 19, consistently the inverse of what should happen with CPU allocation occurs with these processes.

Comment: @csey It may well be that the processes that have a higher priority run for less wall-clock time since they effectively have to wait for shorter amount of time in the run queue. This may give the perception that the use less CPU when viewed in `top`.